# Milestone Violation when Priority is Changed

Tags: servicecloud, entitlements, casemilestone, entitlement-process

Currently facing an issue where milestones are falsely being registered as violated when the priority of a case is changed. Here is how our entitlement process is setup for the first response milestone:

- Priority P1: First response within 60 minutes
- Priority P2: First response within 120 minutes

We've had a number of cases where the case is created as a P2 (which is our default for email-to-case). The agent will respond to a user after 60 minutes, but before 120 minutes, thus not violating the milestone. The agent also in that process realizes that the case is in the wrong priority and updates from P2 -> P1. The milestone that was previously marked as completed and not violated is then updated to a violation status.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: What is the case status before changing the priority? Is there any other milestones got started before changing priority? You can also try to remove entitlement from these cases and later updating priority, add entitlement to the cases.

Comment: Hey Santanu, thanks for the response. I tried removing entitlements, changing statuses, etc. We currently have a case open with salesforce - it looks like this may have been a bug. I will update here when I get more clarity